# Disable button in a third party application?

Tags: linux, mouse, kiosk, hook

Im currently have a linux "kiosk" machine containing a closed-source third party application.

The problem is that the third party application has a settings button, that I dont want the users to be able to mess with. The settings button is always in same place.

Currently, I use a Tk application window in the same size of the button, to cover the button so it cannot be clicked.

The problem is that the application loses focus when the mouse is over the tk application, causing it to behave strangely. The application sometimes display useful info instead of the settings button, so I would want to have the button visible, but unclickable.

The question is: Is there some other way to disable the button (in perl)?
Hooking into the third party application and making the button unclickable, this must be able to be done in a already existing application or in perl?

Is it possible to confine mouse movements, so they must be outside a bounding box? (without constantly refreshing)

Or is it possible to do some global hook of the mouse clicks, and then in a perl script allow/disallow mouse click ("eating" the mouse click or allowing it through) depending on cursor position (if X within A and B, and Y is within C and D, eat mouseclick, else allow it)
Keyboard events should always be allowed through.